# Currency values: Are there names for the parts before and after the decimal point?

Tags: currency, terminology

What is the collective name / term given to the part of a currency value before and after the point?

e.g. $123.99

So in the example above I'm after the name of the part '123' and the name of the part '99'.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just to add some information, percentage in point (PIP)  is used as the smallest unit of change on the foreign exchange market.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_in_point

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A more generic definition applying to all currency denominations would be:

- **Main currency**: for the whole unit currency part left of the decimal point
- **Fractional currency**: for the part to the right of the decimal point usually measured in 1/100 of the main unit (at least in modern times).

For more information, please see [Wikipedia - Currency: Control and production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency#Control_and_production):

> Each currency typically has a main
>   currency unit (the U.S. dollar, for
>   example, or the euro) and a fractional
>   currency, often valued at 1⁄100 of the
>   main currency [...]