# What is the collective name / term given to the part of a currency value before and after the point?

Tags: currency

What is the collective name / term given to the part of a currency value before and after the point?

e.g. $123.99

So in the example above I'm after the name of the part '123' and the name of the part '99'.fter the name of the part '123' and the name of the part '99'.

Comment: This is a copy-paste of a decade-old question that already has an answer. [Currency values: Are there names for the parts before and after the decimal point?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/currency-values-are-there-names-for-the-parts-before-and-after-the-decimal-poin)

Answer (score 11):

- Euros, dollars, pounds etc are called the main currency unit
- cents and pennies are called the fractional unit

Some countries e.g. Japan don't have fractional units.